Is there a way to make nswag behave the same as the swagger export from swaggerhub?
This answer demonstrates the behaviour of swaggerhub - each operationId in the input yaml file gives rise to two methods in the generated cs file, one has the WithHttpInfo suffix, the other does not.
I want to use the nswag tool instead of swaggerhub to generate cs files from the yaml input file. I can successfully run nswag in my project, because I have an OpenApiReference element in my csproj file.
However, the generated cs files do not contain any functions with the WithHttpInfo suffix.
This page lists the nswag command line switches, and I've tried all the likely looking ones, but to no avail.
My question is - are there any nswag command line switches that will cause it to produce pairs of functions like swaggerhub does?

In the cs code generated by nswag I was getting functions with prototypes like this:
public virtual async System.Threading.Tasks.Task PostPdfTemplateAsync(TemplatePdfFieldPost body, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)

The return type is Task which lets me call this function as async. But there's no returned value.
If I add the /WrapResponses:true nswag command line switch, then the generated function signatures change to this:
public virtual async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<SwaggerResponse> PostPdfTemplateAsync(TemplatePdfFieldPost body, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)

So now there is a returned type. The yaml indicates that the REST endpoint sets a Header value in its response, and now I can see that header.
